# How to show active slide number for particular slide

Tags: jquery

I created slider with 3 slides using css3 clip property. Click on slide current slide clips (hide) and show next slide. also given slide number at bottom as 1 2 3 which is not active.

HTML

```js
$('.slide').click(function() {
  var $target = $(this).next();
  if ($target.length == 0)
    $target = $('.slide:first');

  setTimeout(() => $(this).addClass('slide-clip').animate({
    'z-index': 1
  }), 500);
  $target.removeClass('slide-clip').animate({
    'z-index': 3
  });
});
```

```css
.slider-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
}

.slider-wrapper slide h1 {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  width: 95%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 80px 40px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #333;
  clip: rect(0 1060px 660px 0);
  -webkit-transition: linear .5s;
  transition: linear .5s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slide:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #F69B9A;
  /*--magenta shade--*/
  z-index: 3;
}

.slide:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #9DD3D9;
  /*--cyne shade--*/
  z-index: 2;
}

.slide:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #FFBE6A;
  /*--yellow shade--*/
  z-index: 1;
}

.slide-clip {
  clip: rect(0 0 660px 0);
}

.slide-number {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform-x: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 999;
}

.slide-number div {
  padding: 20px 10px;
  opacity: .5;
}

.slide-number {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform-x: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 999;
}

.slide-number div {
  padding: 20px 10px;
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="slides">
    <div class="slide">content1</div>
    <div class="slide">content2</div>
    <div class="slide">content3</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="slide-number">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

Above jquery code is working well to clip slide (animate) on click. I expect that to add jquery for - at start slide number 1 will be default active (opacity 1) and when click on slide, slide number 1 will de-active and next slide number will be active and so on slide number 3.  Or any solution for this. I have basic jquery knowledge and not deep so please can some one help me.

Comment: Hi @Ramesh, could you please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Hi, @mgarica, I updated my css. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need to track the current showed slide and the active slide number and they both have the same index, I would track the current index so that is easier to select both items:

```
var $numbers = $('.slide-number').children();
var $slides = $('.slide');
var numSlides = $slides.length;
var currentSlide = 0;

$('.slide').click(function() {
    currentSlide = (currentSlide + 1) % numSlides;
    var $target = $slides.eq(currentSlide);

    setTimeout(() => {
        $(this).addClass('slide-clip').animate({ 'z-index': 1 });
        $numbers.eq(currentSlide).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    }, 500);
    $target.removeClass('slide-clip').animate({ 'z-index': 3 });
});
```

In the CSS part, you would need to define an `active` class so that the opacity for that number is 1:

```
.slide-number div.active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Lastly, you should set the class `active` for the first item, so that the number 1 has `opacity` 1 at start. Since you are showing the first image with CSS, I would set the class directly in the HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
     <div class="slides">
         <div class="slide">content</div>
         <div class="slide">content</div>
         <div class="slide">content</div>
     </div>
 </div>
 <div class="slide-number">
     <div class="active">1</div>
     <div>2</div>
     <div>3</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you are attempting but here I allow you to click on the numbers OR the "slide"

EDIT: I will leave it up to you to determine the styles. added text to illustrate
NOTE: if you want the animations to appear to be symultantious change like this:

```
currentSlide.removeClass('slide-clip active')
  .animate({
    opacity: 0,
    zIndex: 1,
    duration: 500
//  }, function() { // comment out
});// add me
    nextSlide.addClass('slide-clip active').animate({
      opacity: 1,
      zIndex: 2,
      duration: 500
    });
//  }); comment out
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('.slides').on('click', '.slide', function(event) {
    let slides = $(event.delegateTarget).find('.slide');
    let last = slides.last().index('.slide');
    let currentSlide = $(this);
    let cIdx = currentSlide.index('.slide');
    let nextSlide = (last == cIdx) ? slides.first() : currentSlide.next('.slide');
    // tNext tells the numbers what to highlight
    let tNext = nextSlide.index('.slide');
    $('.numbers').eq(tNext).trigger('highlight');
    currentSlide.removeClass('slide-clip active')
      .animate({
        opacity: 0,
        zIndex: 1,
        duration: 500
      }, function() {
        nextSlide.addClass('slide-clip active').animate({
          opacity: 1,
          zIndex: 2,
          duration: 500
        });
      });
  }); //start first one
  $('.slide-number').on('highlight', 'div', function() {
    $(this).addClass('active')
      .siblings().removeClass('active');
  });

  $('.numbers').on('click', function() {
    let numbers = $('.numbers');
    let slideNumber = $(this);
    slideNumber.trigger('highlight');
    let cIdx = slideNumber.index('.numbers');
    let first = numbers.first().index('.numbers');
    let last = numbers.last('.numbers').index();
    // n is what to tell the slide to click
    let n = (last == cIdx) ? last - 1 : (first == cIdx) ? last : cIdx - 1;
    slideNumber.trigger('highlight');
    $('.slide').eq(n).trigger('click');
  }).first().trigger('click');
});
```

```css
.slides {
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  height: 4em;
}

.slide {
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0.5em;
  left: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  position: absolute;
}

.slide-number {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform-x: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 999;
}

.slide-number div.numbers {
  padding: 20px 10px;
  opacity: .5;
}

.slide-number div.numbers.active {
  background-color: #AAEEEE;
}

.slide.active {
  border: dotted lime 1px;
  background-color: #FFdddd;
}

.slide.slide-clip {
  color: #FF0000;
}

.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="slides">
    <div class="slide ">xxx</div>
    <div class="slide ">yyy big ol text in here</div>
    <div class="slide ">zzz</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="slide-number">
  <div class="numbers">1</div>
  <div class="numbers">2</div>
  <div class="numbers">3</div>
</div>
<div id="showstuff"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please check my updated css. There is no next or prev buttons. There is slider having 3 slides and at bottom number as 1, 2, and 3 for particular slides. All numbers are nt active(opacity 0.5). When I browse my site, 1st slide shows and at bottom 1 number for this slide should shows active as default. When  click  on 1st slide anywhere ,1st slide clips (hide right to left) and next slide (slide number 2) shows. Thus 1st number should de-active and next slides number (number 2) should active and so on. And this is I expect which I tried.

Comment: @Ramesh I adjusted to do what I believe you are attempting